# FirewallD is not running in CentOS Linux 7.1.1503

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I wanted to add a port 5004 for tcp connection. So I run the command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5004/tcp
```

However I got an error:

```
FirewallD is not running
```

So by some research, I run the command to check the status.

```
systemctl status firewalld
```

It shows:

```
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

So what I need to do?

Comment: crashed? Try restarting it (sudo) systemctl start firewalld (sudo if you are not root and may run systemctl start as root using it)

Comment: `systemctl restart firewalld`?

Comment: Thanks, reboot is working. Please convert the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
systemctl restart firewalld
```